delete a jvm-locked file on jvm exit
I have a file that is under lock by the JVM (it is a jar file that provides classes that are loaded at some point during runtime). When my program exits I want to delete this file. However, simply registering it for deletion with File#deleteOnExit() does not do the trick, the file is not deleted. I am assuming this is because the JVM is still running when deleting the files scheduled for deletion and therefore my jar is still under lock. Is there a way to delete files under lock by the JVM on JVM exit? Thanks in advance
PS: I've made sure the JVM terminates naturally, still same result.

Why do you need to delete a jar used by the application?

A jar used by the JVM is not a normal file that you can open and close in your application. They are loaded by the JVM classloader and it makes sense that that deleteOnExit() doesn't work for those, because the JVM may not have close them at that time.
